# How do I load values directly into myCircleArry

Tags: c++, arrays, class

> Here is my class

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
protected:
    int x, y;
    double operator-(const Point& def)
    {
        return sqrt(pow((x - def.x), 2.0) + pow((y - def.y), 2.0));
    }
};

class Circle : public Point {
private:
    int radius;

public:
    Circle()
    { //Point default const called implicitly
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->radius = radius;
    }
    void printCircleInfo()
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << radius << " ";
    }
    bool operator=(const Circle& def)
    {
        return (x == def.x) & (y == def.y) & (radius == def.radius);
    }
    bool doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(Circle anotherCircle)
    {
        if (anotherCircle.radius + radius >= *this - anotherCircle)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Here is main

```
int  main()
{
    const int SIZE = 13;
    Circle myCircleArry[SIZE];

    //I want to load the values 5, 3 and 9 to position 0 of the array. 
    // myCircleArry[0] = { 5, 3, 9 };

    cout << endl;
    cout << myCircleArry[0] << ":";
    ifstream Lab6DataFileHandle;

    Lab6DataFileHandle.open("Lab6Data.txt");
    while (!Lab6DataFileHandle.eof()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            Lab6DataFileHandle >> myCircleArry[i];
            Lab6DataFileHandle >> myCircleArry[i];
            Lab6DataFileHandle >> myCircleArry[i];
            cout << endl;
            if (myCircleArry[0].doIBumpIntoAnotherCircle(myCircleArry[i])) {
                myCircleArry[i].printCircleInfo();
                cout << " ; ";
                if (*this = ) {
                    cout << "*";
                }
            }
        }
        Lab6DataFileHandle.close();
    }
}
```

> How do I load 5 3 and 9 into postion 0 of myCircleArry? If you notice something else wrong with the code please let me know. Please leave an example in your answer it would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Lab6DataFileHandle.close();` you are closing the file in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that.

Comment: `bool operator=(const Circle& def)` should be `bool operator==(const Circle& def)`

Comment: Your Circle constructor doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: Lab6Data.txt is a text file with integers in it but 5 3 and 9 are not a part of it. I need to put them in first in position 0 and fill the rest in using the data from the txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should create a constructor that takes arguments.

It should look something like this:

```
Circle(const Point& pt, int radius)
{
    x = pt.x;
    y = pt.y;
    this->radius = radius;
}
```

or

```
Circle(int x, int y, int radius)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->radius = radius;
}
```

Make sure you still have a default constructor:

```
Circle()
{
    x=y=radius=0;
}
```

At this point you should have at least 2 constructors.

Your question is: `How do I load 5 3 and 9 into postion 0 of myCircleArry?` This is how you'd do it:

```
myCircleArry[0] = Circle(5,3,9);
```

If you'd rather grab it from the file you'd do this (assuming I am assuming your file format is a certain way)

```
int x,y,radius;
Lab6DataFileHandle >> x;
Lab6DataFileHandle >> y;
Lab6DataFileHandle >> radius;
myCircleArry[i] = Circle(x,y,radius);
```

Comment: The change you suggested seemed to have broken my array. I am now getting the error no matching function for call to 'Circle::Circle() any idea why?

Comment: Add a default constructor -- i will update my answer

Comment: There is a question what values a default constructor should set. You could make it set 0 for x,y and radius  or some other state.

Comment: I'm going to assume zero -- which could be a valid scenario?